# How does an android compass application work?

Tags: sensors, compass

I recently installed a Compass app on my phone (it's a HTC Wildfire S if it matters) and I'm curious as how it works.

Found some answers online that the phone's hardware has a digital compass in it, is that it? or is it just a smart use of other sensors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it has a magnetic sensor / digital compass.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Found it in the specs: http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_wildfire_s-3777.php.

Answer (score 2):

Most Android Devices have a [Geomagnetic Field Sensor](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html#sensors-pos-mag) built in. This sensor provides raw field strength data (in μT) for each of the three coordinate axes. You can also use theese values to program things like Metal Detectors.

I programmed one once, if you're interrested in source code let me know.